# Touchpad is not recognized

Tags: touchpad

I've bought a new laptop (Medion Akoya P6647 MD98567) but the touchpad is not recognized.

```
$ uname -a
Linux bookx539 3.15.0-031500-generic #201406131105 SMP Fri Jun 13 15:06:46 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ cat /proc/bus/input/devices
I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0005 Version=0000
N: Name="Lid Switch"
P: Phys=PNP0C0D/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event0 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=1

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0003 Version=0000
N: Name="Sleep Button"
P: Phys=PNP0C0E/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input1
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event1 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=4000 0 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=LNXPWRBN/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event2 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=10000000000000 0

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=ab83
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event3 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=402000000 3803078f800d001 feffffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH Mic"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input4
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event4 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=10

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH Headphone"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input5
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event5 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=4

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=04f2 Product=b3a3 Version=5465
N: Name="USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-10/button
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-10/3-10:1.0/input/input6
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event6 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=100000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0006 Version=0000
N: Name="Video Bus"
P: Phys=LNXVIDEO/video/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:13/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input7
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event7 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=3e000b00000000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0006 Version=0000
N: Name="Video Bus"
P: Phys=LNXVIDEO/video/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:01/input/input8
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event8 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=3e000b00000000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input9
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event9 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input10
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event10 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input11
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event11 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=192f Product=0916 Version=0111
N: Name="USB Optical Mouse"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4:1.0/0003:192F:0916.0001/input/input12
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event12 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=17
B: KEY=70000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=103
B: MSC=10
```

I updated the kernel from 13.13 to 13.15, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: see also bug report about a similar problem: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfree86-driver-synaptics/+bug/374459

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After some more research I've found a solution which is described in [this thread](http://forum.linux-club.de/viewtopic.php?f=92&t=117505) in German.

You have to add `i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop` to the kernel boot options. You can do this permanently by adding these arguments to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` attribute in the file `/etc/default/grub`.

Then it looks like this.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop"
```

After that you just need to enter this command and reboot:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: It worked great but I had to reinstall xserver-xorg-input-synaptics (I found other solutions which said I should uninstall it). All those kernel parameters are described here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt