# Grub Bootloader cause touchpad and trackpoint not working

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, touchpad, bootloader

I have dual boot Windows 10 64bit and Ubuntu Mate 16.04 LTS.

A couple weeks ago in January 2017, after I did system update both for  Windows and maybe for Ubuntu too (not really remember) my touchpad suddenly acting weird.

I Already ask this question in detail here:
https://plus.google.com/113527255489567722959/posts/BgQY9dFybJ6

From my testing, the touchpad is working normal if I use Windows bootable USB flashdrive, so my focus is on the bootloader now.

I use Grub 2.02 beta2, and already edit the file part to below:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="http://i8042.reset quiet splash"

Yes it make positive result, the touchpad now still working after suspend/sleep, except it sleep too long. But still not reliable, often I need to restart the laptop or shutdown many times to make the touchpad & trackpoint work.

Please help, what must I do to fix the problem. How to fix the bootloader?

Thanks for answering.

Device:
Thinkpad x120e 0611 AE5
RAM 4 GB
AMD E350
SSD Samsung 850 Evo 256 GB

Comment: I would say `http://i8042.reset` does nothing. How did you came up with that?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't notice and no idea how that can happen. I copy my question from another forum to this page

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

I edit the grub part as mentioned here:

[Touchpad is not recognized](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525629/touchpad-is-not-recognized)

and here

[Touchpad under 16.04 not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763763/touchpad-under-16-04-not-working)

And get positive result, the touchpad and trackpoint is detected and working more often after system boot. If it not, i found the workaround it is by put the computer to sleep, and repeat as suggested here:
https://www.sevenforums.com/hardware-devices/329195-touchpad-trackpad-inoperable-after-sleep-post3270196.html?s=35750b7293ab81e52bcb45428de94cec#post3270196

Problem solved :)). Thanks.

My Laptop:
Thinkpad x120e
AMD E350, Rodeon 6310
RAM 4 GB
SSD Evo 850 256 GB
Dual Boot:
Windows 10 64 bit
Ubuntu Mate 16.04 LTS