# Touch Pad not working on xubuntu 17.10

Tags: xubuntu, touchpad

I got an Acer Aspire F 15 F5-572G-56CU and my touchpad isn't working.
I already go newest server-xorg-input-synaptics already installed. 
I break my head for about 2 days about this problem. New installed xubuntu on 1 disk drive with 1 partition.
Hope somebody can help me.

Comment: In the search bar above enter `17.10 touchpad` or `17.10 keyboard` for many Q&As. Click on newest and hopefully within you'll find a solution.

Comment: You can also check if the touchpad works under vanilla(main) Ubuntu. Try running Ubuntu from live CD/USB. If touchpad works under Ubuntu and you can't find any solution, you may install Ubuntu and install Xubuntu desktop over it(https://askubuntu.com/questions/65861/how-to-i-change-from-ubuntu-to-xubuntu). As last resort :-)

Answer (score 0):

Get the list of input devices and you will see, if the touchpad is recognized.

> xinput

Also you can search the dconf-editor for the term "touchpad" to see, if its already enabled. Via Terminal:

> dconf-editor

Other suggestions here:

[Grub Bootloader cause touchpad and trackpoint not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/884088/grub-bootloader-cause-touchpad-and-trackpoint-not-working)

Comment: So if i xinput this output occurs:   Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN0501:00 04F3:300B Touchpad            id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer  Razer Abyssus                      id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)] Tried the thing with dconf-editor - didn't work.

Comment: But as u can see my touchpad is recognized.

Comment: Is this a real answer?