# Trackpad not detected for HP Zbook Studio G5 under Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: 18.04, touchpad

I installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 on my new HP laptop. The trackpad/touchpad does not work; it is not detected at all.

Both `xinput -list` and `less /proc/bus/input/devices` do not show any touchpad device.

```
dmesg | grep -i pad
```

also gives no output regarding to the trackpad.

I am aware that the laptop is very new, so I updated the kernel to 4.18.7 as well as 4.19.rc3 (the latest), but with no luck, nothing is detected.

Sorry for my dumb questions, but what should I do in this case? Is this a kernel problem or an Ubuntu distribution problem? Where can I obtain support?

this solution does not work:
[Touchpad is not recognized](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525629/touchpad-is-not-recognized)

**UPDATE**:

As of linux kernel 4.19 stable, the trackpad is fully functional. Ubuntu user needs to manually upgrade the kernel to get it work, or wait until next point release :) cheers

Comment: while booting, while ubuntu is hightlighted in grub, press e to edit and then add the text i8042.reset i8042.nomux after quiet splash and see. `"quiet splash i8042.reset i8042.nomux"`

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem. I test it on ubuntu 16,18 with same result. While I can see the device and set its value to "enable" `xinput set-prop 11 "Device Enabled" 1` it is not working. 
In addition, when I installed `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` or `xserver-xorg-input-all` I have lost keyboard as well and had to re-install. 
Please let me know when the driver is available.

update: adding boot option `acpi=off` works for me but it`s not a solution because the system than can't turn off.

Comment: Hi @pefi, I think this issue is kernel related. I filed a bug here: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201175 . You can help to confirm the issue if it applies, then we cross fingers hope someone can solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was not able to get the touchpad to work using 16.04, but I have gotten it to work with 18.04. I do not remember exactly how I did, however.

First, when you type: `less /proc/bus/input/devices` in the terminal, can you identify a touchpad device?

If that is the case, then you can execute the following:

```
sudo apt-get purge synaptics-touchpad
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

Answer (score 0):

In the HP zbook 15 G5 with ubuntu 18.04 touchpad worked in an erratic manner - sometimes it could work even a day without any reason and then stop abruptly. 
It was still listed in /proc/bus/input/devices. **Upgrading the kernel to 4.19** solved the problem. The new kernel will be included in ubuntu 19.04 (to be released on 18th April 2019).

Comment: Hi whamalai, did you test with the latest point release 18.04.2? the HWE of kernel 4.18 seems to include the fix.

Answer (score 0):

On my zbook 15 G5, after the software update, the touchpad started working, else execute the following command:

sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center

For hanging issue, its a nvidia graphics card issue, so run the following command:
sudo apt-get install nvidia-384