# XMG NEO15 Touchpad is not working

Tags: touchpad

I've bought a new laptop (XMG NEO15, like Gigabyte, I guess) but the touchpad is not recognized.

```
$ uname -a
Linux NEO 4.18.0-10-generic #11-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 11 15:13:55 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v9.0 Mouse    id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v9.0 Consumer Control id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v9.0 Consumer Control id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD Webcam: HD Webcam                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v9.0  id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v9.0 System Control   id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v9.0 Consumer Control id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v9.0 Consumer Control id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I have tried nearly everything I could find including [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525629/touchpad-is-not-recognized) but nothing worked. Now I came across [this post](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/532551-XMG-Neo-Touchpad-wird-nicht-erkannt) (German) in a SUSE discussion board. The guy says his NEO is running now with these patches:

```
wget -O patch1 https://bugzilla.kernel.org/attachment.cgi?id=277217
wget -O patch2 https://bugzilla.kernel.org/attachment.cgi?id=277483
wget -O patch3 https://bugzilla.kernel.org/attachment.cgi?id=277553
wget -O patch4 https://bugzilla.kernel.org/attachment.cgi?id=278563
```

I am quite new to linux. Can I apply these patches and if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved it. Credits go to [@ninetyninezero from the Suse-board](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/532551-XMG-Neo-Touchpad-wird-nicht-erkannt) for the patches.
The right click does not work properly, though...

I started with a virgin v4.18.13 kernel and then compiled a custom version with the patches.
Here the full code, in case anyone else is running into this problem:

```
$ sudo apt install git flex bison bc libssl-dev gawk libudev-dev ocl-icd-opencl-dev libpci-dev libelf-dev python2.7 libncurses-dev fakeroot kernel-wedge binfmt-support ksh lsscsi binfmt-support libpcre16-3 libpcre3-dev libpcre32-3 libpcrecpp0v5 libsepol1-dev libattr1-dev libblkid-dev libpcre16-3 libpcre3-dev libpcre32-3 libpcrecpp0v5 libselinux1-dev libsepol1-dev uuid-dev debugedit libarchive13 libdw1 liblua5.2-0 liblzo2-2 libnspr4 libnss3 librpm8 librpmbuild8 librpmio8 librpmsign8 rpm rpm-common rpm2cpio spl-dkms

$ mkdir kerneltest; cd kerneltest

~/kerneltest$ git clone --depth 1 --single-branch --branch v4.18.13 git://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel-test/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/mainline-crack v4.18.13

~/kerneltest$ cd v4.18.13/
~/kerneltest/v4.18.13$ wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.18.13/0001-base-packaging.patch
~/kerneltest/v4.18.13$ wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.18.13/0002-UBUNTU-SAUCE-add-vmlinux.strip-to-BOOT_TARGETS1-on-p.patch
~/kerneltest/v4.18.13$ wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.18.13/0003-UBUNTU-SAUCE-tools-hv-lsvmbus-add-manual-page.patch
~/kerneltest/v4.18.13$ wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.18.13/0004-debian-changelog.patch
~/kerneltest/v4.18.13$ wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.18.13/0005-configs-based-on-Ubuntu-4.18.0-10.11.patch
~/kerneltest/v4.18.13$ wget -O patch1 https://bugzilla.kernel.org/attachment.cgi?id=277217
~/kerneltest/v4.18.13$ wget -O patch2 https://bugzilla.kernel.org/attachment.cgi?id=277483
~/kerneltest/v4.18.13$ wget -O patch3 https://bugzilla.kernel.org/attachment.cgi?id=277553
~/kerneltest/v4.18.13$ wget -O patch4 https://bugzilla.kernel.org/attachment.cgi?id=278563

~/kerneltest/v4.18.13$ patch -p1 < 0001-base-packaging.patch
~/kerneltest/v4.18.13$ patch -p1 < 0002-UBUNTU-SAUCE-add-vmlinux.strip-to-BOOT_TARGETS1-on-p.patch 
~/kerneltest/v4.18.13$ patch -p1 < 0003-UBUNTU-SAUCE-tools-hv-lsvmbus-add-manual-page.patch 
~/kerneltest/v4.18.13$ patch -p1 < 0004-debian-changelog.patch 
~/kerneltest/v4.18.13$ patch -p1 < 0005-configs-based-on-Ubuntu-4.18.0-10.11.patch 
~/kerneltest/v4.18.13$ patch -p1 < patch1
~/kerneltest/v4.18.13$ patch -p1 < patch2
~/kerneltest/v4.18.13$ patch -p1 < patch3
~/kerneltest/v4.18.13$ patch -p1 < patch4

~/kerneltest/v4.18.13$ cp /boot/config-`uname -r` .config
~/kerneltest/v4.18.13$ yes "" | make oldconfig
~/kerneltest/v4.18.13$ make clean
~/kerneltest/v4.18.13$ make -j `getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN` deb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-custom

~/kerneltest/v4.18.13$ sudo dpkg -i ../*.deb
~/kerneltest/v4.18.13$ sudo update-grub
```

reboot and enjoy.