# Touchpad does not start in ubuntu

Tags: 22.04, touchpad

I have a notebook with a Synaptics TouchPad.
If I

1. Turn on my computer.
2. Start Ubuntu

then my touchpad does not work.

If I

1. Turn on my computer
2. Start Windows
3. Restart my computer
4. Start Ubuntu

then my touchpad works properly.

How can I turn my touchpad on when starting ubuntu?

Comment: Last time I had such problems with a dual-boot system, it had to do with Windows claiming the harddrive and not letting it go. Putting the Windows filesystem/partition on a different drive than the Ubuntu filesystem did the trick. Well, that or simply re-installing grub. Related issue on 16.04: [Synaptic touchpad is not detected on boot, rather, after restart](https://askubuntu.com/q/1126960/393218)

Comment: Disable Windows Fast Startup feature.