# Keyboard and touchpad freeze after suspend

Tags: keyboard, touchpad

I run Ubuntu 19.04 on a VAIO VJF153F11X and have one single issue ever since I started using Linux: every time the system returns from suspend, either built in keyboard and touchpad won't work until I reboot - USB mouse and keyboard work fine.

Had the same problem on 18.04 and Linux Mint. I have already tried:

- Upgrading and downgrading Kernel
- Changing `GRUB_CMD-LIMUX_DEFAULT` line to `"quiet splash i8042 direct i8043 dumbkd"`
- Reinstalling drivers with `install xserver-xorg-input-alll`

None of the above worked, what else can I try?

Comment: Thanks it worked on my Thinkpad-X250 running 20.3 Cinnamon However, in the first attempt what I did was same as yours which led to the disappearance of the Linux Mint logo. I tried again and this time I made sure that I did not delete the 'quiet splash' hence what I did was `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quite splash i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop`and everything was fixed I was able to unfreeze the touchpad and along with that the logo didn't disappear from the boot screen. ☺️

Comment: You're right! I stand corrected! I changed my answer to not touch the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=, and add everything to the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX= instead. This way the addition applies to all kernels and not just to the default one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue with a Toshiba Satellite C50D-A-10K running Debian Buster. When resuming from suspend, both the keyboard and the touchpad wouldn't work. I followed the directions from [this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525629/touchpad-is-not-recognized), and changed the file `/etc/default/grub` adding `i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop` to the line beginning `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` so that it read

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop"
```

Then I updated grub (`sudo update-grub`) and everything works fine now.