# ELAN Touchpad is no longer recognized by synaptics after updating to 21.10

Tags: drivers, touchpad, synaptics, 21.10

After updating my system from 21.04 to 21.10 via `do-release-upgrade`, synaptics seems to either not load at all, or simply does not recognize my touchpad. I've had problems with my touchpad before, but they're usually remedied easily by uninstalling and reinstalling `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`. Now, after updating to 21.10, the touchpad is not recognized (by synaptics) after:

- Repeatedly uninstalling and reinstalling `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`
- Running `modprobe -r psmouse && modprobe psmouse proto=imps`
- `Fn` + `f10` (enable touchpad)
- Adding i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop to grub boot options (https://askubuntu.com/a/528429/40894)
- Forcing insecure boot (sudo mokutil --enable-validation)

However, uninstalling the synaptics driver and rebooting without reinstalling it allowed `libinput` to take control of it (and it continues to have control even after reinstalling xserver-xorg-input-synaptics. `libinput` works, however it's clunky and I would like to be able to go back to using synaptics. In addition to this, KDE Plasma's System Settings reports as no touchpad being detected at all.

`cat /proc/bus/input/devices`

```
I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0005 Version=0000
N: Name="Lid Switch"
P: Phys=PNP0C0D/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:01/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event0 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=1

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=PNP0C0C/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event1 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=10000000000000 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=LNXPWRBN/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event2 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=10000000000000 0

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=ab83
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event3 leds 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=20000 20 0 0 1500f02100000 3803078f900d401 feffffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0006 Version=0000
N: Name="Video Bus"
P: Phys=LNXVIDEO/video/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input15
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event10 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=3e000b00000000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=000e Version=0000
N: Name="ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse4 event11 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=b
B: KEY=e420 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=661800011000003

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HP Wireless hotkeys"
P: Phys=hpq6001/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/virtual/input/input16
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=rfkill kbd event12 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=80000000000000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="Intel HID events"
P: Phys=
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/INT33D5:00/input/input17
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=rfkill kbd event13 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=13
B: KEY=1000300000000 5000004000 1e294000000020 0
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="Intel HID 5 button array"
P: Phys=
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/INT33D5:00/input/input18
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event14 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=13
B: KEY=2000000000000 0 0 0 0 1000000000000 0 201c000000000000 0
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HP WMI hotkeys"
P: Phys=wmi/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/virtual/input/input19
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event4 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=33
B: KEY=4000000000 0 1000700000000 2102400 0 0
B: MSC=10
B: SW=20

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=30c9 Product=000e Version=0002
N: Name="HP Wide Vision HD Camera: HP Wi"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-6/button
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-6/3-6:1.0/input/input20
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event5 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=100000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0018 Vendor=04f3 Product=2b55 Version=0100
N: Name="ELAN2513:00 04F3:2B55"
P: Phys=i2c-ELAN2513:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-1/i2c-ELAN2513:00/0018:04F3:2B55.0001/input/input21
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event6 
B: PROP=2
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=400 0 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=3273800000000003
B: MSC=20

I: Bus=0018 Vendor=04f3 Product=2b55 Version=0100
N: Name="ELAN2513:00 04F3:2B55 UNKNOWN"
P: Phys=i2c-ELAN2513:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-1/i2c-ELAN2513:00/0018:04F3:2B55.0001/input/input22
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event7 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=9
B: ABS=10000000000

I: Bus=0018 Vendor=04f3 Product=2b55 Version=0100
N: Name="ELAN2513:00 04F3:2B55 UNKNOWN"
P: Phys=i2c-ELAN2513:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-1/i2c-ELAN2513:00/0018:04F3:2B55.0001/input/input23
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event15 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=100001

I: Bus=0018 Vendor=04f3 Product=2b55 Version=0100
N: Name="ELAN2513:00 04F3:2B55 Stylus"
P: Phys=i2c-ELAN2513:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-1/i2c-ELAN2513:00/0018:04F3:2B55.0001/input/input24
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event16 
B: PROP=2
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=c03 0 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=1000d000003
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="Intel HID switches"
P: Phys=
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/INT33D5:00/input/input27
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event8 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=2

I: Bus=0018 Vendor=04f3 Product=3139 Version=0100
N: Name="ELAN0722:00 04F3:3139 Mouse"
P: Phys=i2c-ELAN0722:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-2/i2c-ELAN0722:00/0018:04F3:3139.0002/input/input28
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse2 event9 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=17
B: KEY=30000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=3
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0018 Vendor=04f3 Product=3139 Version=0100
N: Name="ELAN0722:00 04F3:3139 Touchpad"
P: Phys=i2c-ELAN0722:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-2/i2c-ELAN0722:00/0018:04F3:3139.0002/input/input30
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse3 event17 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=2e0800000000003
B: MSC=20

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="sof-hda-dsp Mic"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card0/input31
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event18 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=10

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="sof-hda-dsp Headphone"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card0/input32
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event19 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=4

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=3"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card0/input33
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event20 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=4"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card0/input34
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event21 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=5"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card0/input35
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event22 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140
```

`xinput`

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN2513:00 04F3:2B55                     id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN0722:00 04F3:3139 Mouse               id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN0722:00 04F3:3139 Touchpad            id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wide Vision HD Camera: HP Wi           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ELAN2513:00 04F3:2B55 Stylus              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wireless hotkeys                       id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

`synclient`

```
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
```

`sudo dmesg | grep psmouse`

```
[    1.385308] psmouse serio1: elantech: assuming hardware version 4 (with firmware version 0x6f1001)
[    1.397747] psmouse serio1: elantech: Synaptics capabilities query result 0x00, 0x1a, 0x10.
[    1.409880] psmouse serio1: elantech: Elan sample query result 00, 62, a8
[    1.421882] psmouse serio1: elantech: Elan ic body: 0x10, current fw version: 0x3
```

Comment: Experiencing similar problem here. Did you fix it?