# Touchpad not working after update

Tags: mouse, touchpad, 21.04, synaptics

I use a HP NoteBook 15 and formatted the laptop and installed ubuntu in it. The touchpad works with the initial version of the kernel. After I ran `sudo apt-get upgrade` it stopped detecting the touchpad. I tried many solutions but nothing worked.

I tried this solution- [Touchpad is not recognized](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525629/touchpad-is-not-recognized)
but still it did not work.

When I run `xinput list` this is the output,

```
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:17                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:17              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:17                      id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

The touchpad is not detected here.

Comment: Are you running Wayland of X11/xorg? Try X11/xorg. Also, you can try booting to an older kernel via the GRUB menu and see if that fixes things.

Comment: A good place to start any question is what version of Ubuntu you are using.

Comment: I am using 21.04 LTS